# Log4j For Each Class in Project

Tags: java, log4j

I have a project containing classes.

I would like to do logging per class instead of wrapping them up altogether in a single log file. I am using Java.

Like for example I have

foo.bar.class1
foo.bar.class2

How can I achieve log file per class?

So that I could have a log file named "class1.log" and "class2.log" containing their own respective log data. What should I do in log4j.properties or on classes?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you were to use the `log4j-slf4j` bridge then plug in a `logback` backend you could use a [`SiftingAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) to "sift" different logs into different files. I'm not sure such functionality is available with only log4j.

Comment: create logger for every class and associate each logger with separate appender with there own log files.

Comment: With Log4j, I think you would need to write a custom appender to do this.  But really don't think this is a good idea.  Tracking problems across method call sequences involving multiple classes could be exceedingly awkward.

Comment: @NaveenRamawat how could I achieve it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this in log4j.xml or log4j.properties. So what you can actually do is this (untested, but should work in this fashion):

```
static {
    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    try {
        ((FileAppender)LOG.getAppender()).setFile("class-" + MyClass.name());
    } catch (...) {}
}
```